# CIM_Battery WMI Class has no instances

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wmi

I am trying to create a C# Application that records the battery percentage over time, and to do that I have been trying to use the .NET WMI API. I looked on MSDN and found that there is a WMI class called [`CIM_Battery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387189(v=vs.85).aspx#properties), and confirmed its existence with [`wbemtest.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc180684.aspx).

The only issue with this method is that apparently the `CIM_Battery` class has no instances that I can read from.

[image: No instances!]

I know of battery monitor software that successfully reads the battery percentage on my laptop, so I know it is possible on my laptop. Am I trying to use the wrong tool for the job?

Comment: [SystemInformation.PowerStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.powerstatus(v=vs.110).aspx)    => `.BatteryChargeStatus`,  `.BatteryLifePercent` `.BatteryLifeRemaining`.

Comment: @Jimi That does work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it incorrectly. From the [MSDN Page for the `CIM_Battery` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387189(v=vs.85).aspx#properties):

> **Important**: The DMTF (Distributed Management Task Force) CIM (Common
>   Information Model) classes are the parent classes upon which WMI
>   classes are built.

`CIM_[WHATEVER]` classes are just templates or models for what another class can implement. In the case of a battery, the proper WMI class to look at is [`win32_battery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394074(v=vs.85).aspx) class, which implements the `CIM_Battery` model.

[image: win32_battery inherits from cim_battery as shown in wbemtest.exe]